# com.example.main cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, manifest

Just following the basic android documentation on [FragmentTabHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) (top example - FragmentTabHost in an Activity) and received the following error:

```
10-21 02:30:07.409  26265-26265/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.Main cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

What's strange is that I've followed everything properly and installed the necessary packages.

**Main.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
                Main.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
                ListNewItem.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
                Favourites.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Tab4"),
                Notifications.class, null);
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

**Note:** Intellij displays the following in the side-window when attempting to display a preview:

> Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for
>   tag null

Library bug maybe?

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/main"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Notifications.java (badly named fragment)**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Favourites extends Fragment  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourites, container, false);

        return V;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why I'm having the problems with both the rendering and why the class conversion isn't working?

Comment: set tag..for the tabs -(fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what you see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) we need to pass Fragment class, not FragmentActivity to the addTab() function.

in here you are passing `Main.Class`

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
                Main.class, null);
```

Which is a FragmentActivity Class not a Fragment

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity
```

See this part

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
```

They are passing FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class which is a Fragment

To make you more sure see this grepcode link of android source code for FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment -> [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentStackSupport.java#FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment)

That will explain why you are getting java.lang.ClassCastException because you are passing wrong type of class.

Comment: I'm using the top example, "FragmentTabHost in an Activity"

Comment: I am passing fragments, Notifications.class etc are just badly named. I will show you what it looks like

Comment: @newb Maybe you didn't notice but you are passing Main.Class, see my updated answer :)

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks loads, the problem is, I wanted to use this Main.class activity (it's actually the homepage) as the first tab (like what instagram has) so I can tap and be back on homepage. Is there anyway for me to temporarily pass it as a fragment so I can go back to this activity screen

Comment: @newb sadly no, but from my advice, you will need to redesign your activity for container only, and put all the replaceable view in the tab. In that way you have more flexibility :)